# How to cross compile tesseract ocr engine for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ocr, tesseract

I am struggling from past 1 week that how to compile the tesseract ocr enging for iphone. I have gon through through some link, But i couldn't find the proper way. Can anyone help me through step by step procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u complete the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably won't be enough. I know nothing about Tesseract OCR library but you will require the include directives, plus specify the directory to where the Tesseract header files are installed via a compiler switch (usually -I) and (possibly) link with the Tesseract library file(s). 
That would be enough to compile the sources if the header files are installed into common include directories. However, if the header files do not contain the definitions (not just declarations) for all functions/variables then there will be a library file(s) (like libtesseract.a or/and libtesseract.so) that must be linked in order to compile your binary.

Answer (score 1):

I will have to agree with you on this that it is not an easy task, but the below links finally helped me achieve this... hoping this helps..

http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/

Comment: I tried the way as i explained in the first link. But i stuck with Project Configuration step. Can you help me .